# Javascript Database API return result

Tags: javascript, html

Hey all I've just been fooling around with the HTML5 Database API and I'm having trouble return the result from a function. Here is what I have.

```
var list = GetScenarios();

GetScenarios: function()
{

var scenarios;

// get all the scenarios
conn.transaction(function(_t) {

_t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM scenarios', [], function(_tr, _result) {

        scenarios = _result.rows;

    });
});

return scenarios;

}
```

I manage to get the rows from the db but the rows wont assign to the variable scenarios. I know its a scope thing but I can't think how to return the result from the GetScenatios function.

When I log _result.rows I have the data there but scenario is always undefined;

Any thoughts?

Here is how my js file is setup.

```
window.MyExtension = (function() 
{

    return ({

    OtherMethod: function() {   


        var list = window.MyExtension.GetScenarios();

    },

    GetScenarios: function() {

         ...see above

    }

}());
```

Comment: Your code is invalid JavaScript.  `GetScenarios: function()` should be `function GetScenarios()`.  It could be `GetScenarios = function()` but then it would have to appear before `var list = GetScenarios();`.

Comment: @gilly3, correct, except for the last remark: http://jsfiddle.net/FvdbT/

Comment: @stivlo - Perhaps you misread my comment.  `function GetScenarios()` works, as proven by your jsFiddle.  But, `GetScenarios = function()` does not, as evidenced by this one: http://jsfiddle.net/FvdbT/1/

Comment: GetScenarios: function() works. I edited the post to reflect the js file setup

Comment: @gilly3 yes, I agree with that. hooligan, open your JavaScript console, for instance FireBug, and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry should have put up my proper setup. No JS errors

Comment: so maybe you've copied your code incorrectly. `GetScenarios: function()`, doesn't work should be `=` or declare as function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to return code from an asynchronous request as though it were synchronous.  You need to add a callback parameter to `GetScenarios()`:

```
function GetScenarios(callback) {
    conn.transaction(function(_t) {
        _t.executeSql('...', [], function(_tr, _result) {
            callback(_result.rows);
        });
    });
}
```

And change your calling code from:

```
var list = GetScenarios();
// do something with list
```

To, this:

```
GetScenarios(function (list) {
    // do something with list
});
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you so much. Also turns out I have to use window.MyExtension.GetScenario() from within the object. Thanks Heaps